# Is onto function necessarily a function?

Tags: functions

The standard definition suggests that every element in the codomain should have a preimage. So, Can different elements in codomain or range have same domain?
A worst question I think. Please reply...

Comment: Koushik,  yes, an "onto function" is implicitly a function, not some other kind of relation.

Comment: Different elements in the co-domain cannot have the same element in the domain mapping to them.  But you can have multiple elements of the domain map to the same element in the co-domain.  But that has nothing to do with a function being onto.  An onto function means every element in the co-domain has at least one element in the domain mapping to it.

Comment: An onto function is definitely a function. It's not like "tall Pygmy" or "trim sumo wrestler".

Comment: There are a few occurrences of the word "function" where a modifying word actually makes it a non-function. "Multi-valued function," for example, and "partial function," and even "meromorphic function." @BrianO :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  with apologies, i delete my comment. Thanks

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Great (counter)examples to any alleged general statement. "Multi-valued function" is the best, safe to say — an outright oxymoron :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A *function* $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ is a relation between the elements of $A$ and $B$ satisfying a key property: if $f(a)=b$ and $f(a)=b^{\prime}$, $b=b^{\prime}$.

That is, a function maps an input to only ONE element.

> An *onto function* **is a function** $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ satisfying the following property: if $b$ is an element of $B$, there exists an $a$ in $A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Intuitively, for each output, you can find an input that will produce that output.

---

Note that there could be more than one element mapping to each $b$ in $B$. For example, $f(a)=f(a^{\prime})=b$. If $C\subset B$, we can define the preimage of $C$ as
$$
f^{-1}(C)\equiv\left\{ a\in A\colon f(a)\in C\right\} .
$$
If $C$ is a singleton (i.e. $C=\{c\}$ for some $c\in B$), we often drop the set braces $\{\cdot\}$:
$$
f^{-1}(c)\equiv f^{-1}(\{c\}).
$$
We can now restate the definition of onto in terms of preimages of singletons:

> An *onto function* is a function $f\colon A\rightarrow B$ satisfying the following property: for each $b$ in $B$, $f^{-1}(b)$ is nonempty.